# Retrieve number of unique values in an string

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to populate an array with all the unique values in a string, to prevent me ReDim'ing an array every time I find a value that not already contained in the array I am trying to create (consumes alot of time), I am trying to get the unique values first so I only have to ReDim once and after that I can simply iterate through the string and the array I have will be the correct size for the unique values I aquire (I am using this...)

```
If array.Contains(string.Chars(atvalue)) = False Then...
```

How can I get the number of unique values easily and quickly?

Cheers
Martin

Comment: Please tag this correctly. This is not VB6. I guess you are using VB.NET?

Comment: What do you mean this is not VB6? I am using Visual studio 2010 and the language is visual basic..

Comment: It is definatly VB6 as I have checked and it says Visual basic, not visual basic.net (unless in visual studio 2010 vb = vb.net )

Comment: It is definitely? Then how do you know it is not Visual Basic 5 or even Visual Basic 4? [Have a read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic).

Comment: This question is a duplicate of your own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746609/array-creation-and-population-issues-in-visual-basic I just lost 30 minutes answering that while it was already answered here. Please take care of such things.

Comment: @marscom: so if your are using VS 2010, it is definitely VB.NET (or VB 10.0, due to MS versioning scheme, se here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET), and not VB6. Nowadays, MS calls VB.Net often just "VB", that's marketing strategy.

Comment: Thanks Doc, that clarified that - as for dabblernl, sorry about that, a duplicate was not intended and apologies for wasting your valuable time - I'll try to not let that happen again, thanks for the help aswell :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "values" you mean "characters," then

```
Dim s As String = "dfgsdg"
Dim uc = s.Distinct().ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are literally looking for is:

```
Public Function GetUniqueChars(text As String) As Char()
        Dim uniqueChars() As String
        uniqueChars=""

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) Then Return uniqueChars

        uniqueChars &= text(0)

        For Each c In text.Substring(1)
            If Not uniqueChars.Contains(c) Then
                uniqueChars &= c
            End If
        Next

        Return uniqueChars.ToArray

    End Function
```

However, starting with Net 3.5 you can use LINQ to reduce this function to one line:

```
uniqueChars = text.Distinct().ToArray
```